# How do I inject keys into JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, google-api

I’m building a To Do style app with React.js + node.js + Express + Google sheets API to fetch data. The app returns data in JSON as planned, however it won’t recognize my headers as keys. I need to inject the keys somehow. I think it’s some combo of a foreach loop and map function but I’m struggling to get it right. Any advice on either fetching headers with the Google Sheets API OR restructuring the JSON data response to include headers as show below?

**Current response (note: actions[0] represents the desired keys)**

```
{"actions": [["Title", "Url", "Status"],["Volunteer", "www.apple.com", "false "],["Write a Letter", "www.google.com", "false "]]}
```

**Desired response**

```
{"actions": [[Title: "Volunteer", Url: "www.apple.com", Status: "false "], [Title: "Write a Letter", Url: "www.google.com", Status: "false "]]}
```

index.js

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    const readline = require('readline');
    const {google} = require('googleapis');
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    
    const app = express();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 1234;
    
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      next();
    });
    
    // If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
    const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';
    /**
       * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
       * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
       * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
       * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
       */
      function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
        const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
          access_type: 'offline',
          scope: SCOPES,
        });
        console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
          input: process.stdin,
          output: process.stdout,
        });
        rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
          rl.close();
          oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
            if (err) return console.error('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
            // Store the token to disk for later program executions
            fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
              if (err) return console.error(err);
              console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
            });
            callback(oAuth2Client);
          });
        });
      }
    
    
      function authorize(credentials, callback) {
        const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
        const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
            client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);
    
        // Check if we have previously stored a token.
        fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
          if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
          oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
          callback(oAuth2Client);
        });
      }
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    
      // Load client secrets from a local file.
      fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
        if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
        // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
        authorize(JSON.parse(content), listActions);
      });
    
      function listActions(auth) {
        const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
        sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
          spreadsheetId: 'SHEET_ID',
          range: 'LevelOne!A1:C20'
    
        }, (err, response, sheets)=>{
          if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
          
          // (3) Setting data for daily tracking
    
          let actions = response.data.values
    
         res.json({ actions: actions})
        })
      }
    });
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: `[Title: "Volunteer", Url: "www.apple.com", Status: "false "]` is not valid. You can only use `key:value` in objects, not arrays. So it should be `{Title: "Volunteer", Url: "www.apple.com", Status: "false "}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested loops. The outer loop processes the elements of the `actions` array after the list of keys has been removed. The inner loop creates objects dynamically using the keys.

```js
let actions = [["Title", "Url", "Status"],["Volunteer", "www.apple.com", "false "],["Write a Letter", "www.google.com", "false "]];
let action_keys = actions.shift(); // remove actions[0]
let action_objects = actions.map(action => {
    let obj = {};
    action_keys.forEach((key, i) => obj[key] = action[i]);
    return obj;
});
console.log(action_objects);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing,

```js
let actions = response.data.values
```

with

```js
const names = response.data.values[0]; // Get the field names
const entries = response.data.values.slice(1); // Get the field values

const actions = entries.map(entry => {
  const fieldWithName = (field, i) => {
    const fieldName = names[i]; // Get the field name by index
    return [fieldName, field]; // Create a pair of [key, value]
  };
  return Object.fromEntries(entry.map(fieldWithName)); // Create object from list of [key, value] pairs
});
```